# is it really worthy to have a SharedPreferencesLoader instead of system default?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, loader

I figured out supporting 2+ loaders in the same activity. use the first argument loaderId to switch for different loaders. For SharedPreferencesLoader, just create a field object subclassing from Loader.CallBack and pass it as the last argument into LoadManager initLoader method. The question is: is it really worthy to have a SharedPreferencesLoader instead of system default? Any evidence to justify its use?

Answer (score 0):

What is a SharedPreferencesLoader? Did you write this yourself? There's no reason to have an asynchronous loader for accessing SharedPreferences.

Comment: "What is a SharedPreferencesLoader?" -- see https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-loaderex. "Did you write this yourself?" -- no, I did. "There's no reason to have an asynchronous loader for accessing SharedPreferences" -- originally, the first time you referenced a `SharedPreferences` would perform a disk I/O on the current thread. Now, while it does fork a thread, you still block the current thread when you first try reading/writing from the preferences, as the `SharedPreferences` API was not written with asynchronous loading in mind.

Comment: Hence, you can still block the main application thread waiting for the disk I/O to complete. Using a `Loader` is overkill, to be certain, but since the `SharedPreferences` API does not give us any sort of `OnLoadCompletionListener`, just about anything we do to avoid blocking the main application thread will be overkill. If you have a better pattern, please write it up somewhere.